# Wrong number of arguments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm following Michael Hartl's tutorial [here](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#sec:user_index) and am trying to create an index of users.

My code:

```
  class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update]
  .
  .
  .
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
  .
  .
  .
  end
```

and

```
<%= provide(:title, 'All users') %>
<h1>All users</h1>

<ul class="users">
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <li>
      <%= gravatar_for user, size: 52 %>
      <%= link_to user.name, user %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

I've made sure my code matches the code in the tutorial exactly, but I'm getting this error:

```
wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
```

What am I doing wrong? Any thoughts?

Comment: What line of code are you getting this error?  Could you show your trace?

Comment: Knowing what statement that's causing the error would be useful. But in essence you're passing two wrguments to a method that only takes one argument.

Comment: **Solved the problem** turns out it was a mistake in `gravatar_for`. Sorry!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to the tutorial, the gravatar_for method is defined as

```
def gravatar_for(user)
  gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
  gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}"
  image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "gravatar")
end
```

Notice that it only accepts one parameter: the user. [Later in chapter 7](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#code%3agravatar_option), after the exercises, the tutorial describes how to add a size parameter:

```
# Returns the Gravatar (http://gravatar.com/) for the given user.
def gravatar_for(user, options = { size: 50 })
  gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
  size = options[:size]
  gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}?s=#{size}"
  image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "gravatar")
end
```

Judging by your error message, you haven't updated the method to use the optional size parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If you followed the tutorial and added the options hash to the function then you're only missing the {} around the options.

This should work.
`<%= gravatar_for user, {size: 52} %>`

Comment: It was actually a mistake in the gravatar_for function itself. Thanks though!

Comment: Ruby doesn't require the braces as long as the hash is the last part of the arguments.

Answer (score -1):

Check here:

```
<%= gravatar_for user, :size => 52 %>
```