# wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) RoR error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to make a simple app, and on my index page, I am running into the error:

```
wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
```

The view looks like so (index.html.slim):

```
- provide(:title, 'All users')
h1
  | All users
ul.users
  - @users.each do |user|
    li
      = gravatar_for user, size: 50
      = link_to user.name, user
```

The error is pointing to the line:

```
= gravatar_for user, size: 50
```

Any idea why I am getting this error?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```
= gravatar_for user
```

See also [Wrong number of arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916705/wrong-number-of-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

The options for gravatar_for should be in an options hash:

```
gravatar_for(user, options = { size: 50 }) ⇒ Object
```

[See this](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed/UsersHelper:gravatar_for).